# What is a Dictimporter sources for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

The code at:

https://github.com/baojie/smw/blob/master/runtests.py

Starts with a declaration of a large binary "sources" variable.

Then it does some magic like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        exec("def do_exec(co, loc): exec(co, loc)\n")
        import pickle
        sources = sources.encode("ascii")  # ensure bytes
        sources = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(base64.decodebytes(sources)))
    else:
        import cPickle as pickle
        exec("def do_exec(co, loc): exec co in loc\n")
        sources = pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(base64.decodestring(sources)))

    importer = DictImporter(sources)
    sys.meta_path.append(importer)

    entry = "import py; raise SystemExit(py.test.cmdline.main())"
    do_exec(entry, locals())
```

My first impression would be that someone is about to try to hack my computer with this.

**What's the real magic behind this?**

Comment: i'm not keen to actually run this on my system to test, but it is possible to put malicious code in `pickle` objects https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html